# DBMS SCHEDULER Job with input

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

Hi I have a stored procedure in oracle that I would like to run periodically. Firstly I got my DBMS_SCHEDULER Job to compile **(see below)** and I can even see the job be created and drop it though I don't see the result of the stored procedure occur in the table it is supposed to effect and the stored procedure has been tested.

```
BEGIN                      
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB ( 
   job_name        => 'JOB_QUERY',
   job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',       -- see oracle documentation on types --
   job_action      => 'BEGIN RUNREPORT(''NAME'', ''VERSION'', ''04-Jun-13'', ''11-Jun-13''); END;',
   start_date      => to_date('2013-08-19 16:35:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ),
   repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;BYMINUTE=10',    -- every 10 minutes.
   end_date        => NULL, 
   enabled         => TRUE,
   comments        => 'Daily Jira Query Update');
END;
```

I was attempting to simply make it run every ten minutes though I see no changes. Also I wanted to be able to pass SYSDATE or the current date to the procedure in the dbms_scheduler job but I cant get it to work with the apostrophes.

Thanks

Comment: is my repeat interval right if i wanna do it every 10 minutes?

repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;BYMINUTE=10'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `COMMIT` your DML statements. There is no `COMMIT` in PL/SQL block and I guess in procedure `RUNREPORT` either.

You don't need an apostrophe around sysdate, it's not a string literal.

```
job_action      => 'BEGIN RUNREPORT(''NAME'', ''VERSION'', sysdate, ''11-Jun-13''); COMMIT; END;',
```

`BYMINUTE` does not mean what you would expect. From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#CIHCGBDD): 
"This specifies the minute on which the job is to run. Valid values are 0 to 59. As an example, 45 means 45 minutes past the chosen hour". What you need is

```
repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=10'
```

You can check next run date and more by querying `user_scheduler_jobs`.

Comment: I tried putting commit statements in the job_action. And even replacing the run report with a far more simple single insert into a test table and got no results.

Comment: I'm sorry I should check repeat_interval at the first place. Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the stored procedure from DMBS Scheduled job you can try below.

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
      JOB_NAME              => 'SCHEMA.MY_DBMS_SCHEDULED_JOB',
      JOB_TYPE              => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
      JOB_ACTION            => 'SCHEMA.STORED_PROCEDURE_TO_BE_CALLED',
      START_DATE            => '01-AUG-13 12.00.00 AM',
      REPEAT_INTERVAL       => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=0;BYMINUTE=10', 
      AUTO_DROP             => FALSE,
      ENABLED               => TRUE,
      NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS   => 0,
      COMMENTS              => 'Scheduled job to perform updates.');
END;
/
```

To see if your scheduler log you can use below query.

```
SELECT * FROM all_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG 
   where job_name='MY_DBMS_SCHEDULED_JOB' 
      order by log_id desc;
```